# Rounding pandas column to year

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Python and Pandas beginner here.

I want to round off a pandas dataframe column to years. Dates before the 1st of July must be rounded off to the current year and dates after and on the 1st of July must be rounded up to the next year.

For example:

`2011-04-05` must be rounded to `2011`

`2011-08-09` must be rounded to `2012`

`2011-06-30` must be rounded to `2011`

`2011-07-01` must be rounded to `2012`

What I've tried:

`pd.series.dt.round(freq='Y')`

Gives the error: `ValueError: <YearEnd: month=12> is a non-fixed frequency`

The dataframe column has a wide variety of dates, starting from 1945 all the way up to 2021. Therefore a simple `if df.date < 2011-07-01: df['Date']+ pd.offsets.YearBegin(-1)` is not working.

I also tried the `dt.to_period('Y')` function, but then I can't give the before and after the 1st of July argument.

Any tips on how I can solve this issue?

Comment: A quick fix is to add a time delta of 6 months and then just take the year. Probably easier than looking up the rounding in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have this dataframe:

```
       dates
0 2011-04-05
1 2011-08-09
2 2011-06-30
3 2011-07-01
4 1945-06-30
5 1945-07-01
```

Then:

```py
# convert to datetime:
df["dates"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dates"])

df["year"] = np.where(
    (df["dates"].dt.month < 7), df["dates"].dt.year, df["dates"].dt.year + 1
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
       dates  year
0 2011-04-05  2011
1 2011-08-09  2012
2 2011-06-30  2011
3 2011-07-01  2012
4 1945-06-30  1945
5 1945-07-01  1946
```

Answer (score 0):

a bit of a roundabout year is to convert the date values to strings, separate them, and then classify them in a loop, like so:

```
for i in df["Date"]: # assuming the column's name is "Date"

   thisdate = df["Date"] # extract the ith element of Date
   thisdate = str(thisdate) # convert to string
   datesplit = thisdate.split("-") # split

   Yr = int(datesplit[0]) # get the year # convert year back to a number
   Mth = int(datesplit[1]) # get the month # convert month back to a number

   if Mth < 7: # any date before July
      rnd_Yr = Yr
   else: # any date after July 1st
      rnd_Yr = Yr + 1
```